# ipcs(1) POSIX equivalent to System V

Tags: posix, ipc

I know that with ipcs(1) command, one can monitor System V message queues, shared memory and semaphores, but how do I monitor POSIX message queues, shared memory and semaphores. For POSIX message queues, I can mount a pseudo filesystem, as stated in mq_overview(7). Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there are any commands that allow you to monitor POSIX message queues specifically.

As you mentioned, all of the details are exposed via a pseudo filesystem, usually mounted under `/dev/mqueue`. Once you've done that, you can then use file management commands like `ls`, `rm`, `cat`, etc. to inspect and manage the queue details.

Comment: And for shared memory and semaphore, you can look in /dev/shm because POSIX creates its objects in a tmpfs.